# Arduino fading details

Tags: c++, arduino

shouldn't the code I will post bellow allow me to fade an RGB LED from 0 to 255 and then back to 0 and so on in an infinite loop?

At the moment it just fades growing big but then it doesn t fade out, it does blink for a bit but then it is again fully powered at 255.

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);

fade = 0;

}

void loop()
{

   while(fade < 256)
   {
    analogWrite(redPin, fade);
   delay(30);
   analogWrite(greenPin, fade );
   delay(30);
   analogWrite(bluePin, fade);
   delay(30);
   fade++;
   }
   while(fade > 0)
   {
      analogWrite(redPin, fade);
   delay(30);
   analogWrite(greenPin, fade );
   delay(30);
   analogWrite(bluePin, fade);
   delay(30);
   fade--;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If fade is a byte:

fade goes to 256 -> 00!
so the second loop would be "very short" :-)

I suggest in the first loop use only:

```
while(fade < 255)
```

then it stops at 255 e.g. 0xff

and the second while should run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about a single loop forever:

```
fade = 0;
step = 1;
while(1)
   {
   step = fade == 0 ? 1 : (fade == 255 ? -1 : step);
   fade += step;
   analogWrite(redPin, fade);
   delay(30);
   analogWrite(greenPin, fade );
   delay(30);
   analogWrite(bluePin, fade);
   delay(30);
   }
```